# Wrong constant on FragmentStatePagerAdapter constructor

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I extend my adapter with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and pass the arguments with fragment manager and the constant `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` to the constructor I receive an error on lint with the message "wrong constant".

I've checked on the documentation if the constant is the correct one, and is everything ok compared with my code.

My question is, Why Lint gives me this error if I'm doing this correctly?

My Adapter code:

```
class CardBannerAdapter(
    fm: FragmentManager
) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(
   fm, androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT
) {

}
```

Comment: It seems correct

Comment: Yes, seems ok, but Lint give me this error. I don't know why Lint do that.

Comment: It seems a cache problem, mine lint works fine, try clean project and run `gradlew lint` in terminal to see if it still happen

Comment: After clean project and run `gradlew lint` the problem still happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by upgrading build tools in project build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```